# How do I iptables-restore maintaining some dynamic chains?

Tags: iptables, docker

When using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`, all chains are saved and restored no matter what. I'm wondering if it would be possible to restore with exceptions to some specific chains. E.g. when using Docker and Fail2ban you'll have chains managed by the application which contain dynamic entries you don't want to wipe and overwrite.

I've spotted the `--noflush` option to the `iptables-restore` command, however, that will still flush the user defined chains.

So, let's say an `iptables-save > /path/to/rules-v4` looks like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
# -A DOCKER <- commented, dynamic chain
[...]
```

and I will restore this with `iptables-restore -n < /path/to/rules-v4`, all chains including the `DOCKER` chain are still flushed. Confusing, but solved that part:

Now, if I comment the `:DOCKER - [0:0]` line, the `DOCKER` chain left in tact. However, now the command fails on reboot when the Docker service hasn't created the `DOCKER` chain yet, because there's a reference to it from the `PREROUTING` chain.

So... Meh. How do you guys solve this chicken-and-egg problem? Is it possible to ensure the existence of a chain in `iptables-restore` without touching the entries?

<sup>(Please don't suggest to start Docker before the netfilter-persistent service, that's just plain ugly.)</sup>

Comment: With firewalld, and avoiding Debian-based distributions.

Comment: Oh I should check out firewalld. Ubuntu provides this package, though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about wrapping the `iptables-save` command and strip out from the result file the rules that you don't want, generating a new result file ready to be used by `iptables-restore` with just the chains that you want?

Comment: Yeah, of course, writing a solution your own in a script will work. Was hoping for a more general robust approach though.